# IIS 7.5 URL Rewrite rule to handle request based on user agent

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I have written a rule to redirect request based on user agent. The rule is set to redirect default requests (not mobile) to `Domain1` and requests from mobile devices to a mobile domain, `Domain2`.

Even after applying the mobile redirect, all requests from mobile are taken to `Domain1`.

See the redirect rule below. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

```xml
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Mobile UA redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^.*BlackBerry.*$ " />
        <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern=".*Mobile.*Safari" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="Domain2" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Claritinchallenge to" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="Domain1" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `Mobile UA redirect` rule, the conditions logical grouping is the one by default: `MatchAll`

I don't think a phone having a `HTTP_USER_AGENT` matching `^.*BlackBerry.*$` will also match `.*Mobile.*Safari`. So you need to change the logical grouping to `MatchAny`.

You rule would then be:

```xml
<rule name="Mobile UA redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
    <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^.*BlackBerry.*$ " />
    <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern=".*Mobile.*Safari" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="MobileURL" />
</rule>
```

Comment: @b00tbu9 well, that's weird. Can you give `MatchAny` a try?